# Update <div> with JSONP value jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm getting the temperature from a service called [World Weather Online](http://developer.worldweatheronline.com/io-docs)

I'm trying to update the weather into my `<span>` content like this: (I have all the values correct, it just doesn't change the value when I open my page)

```
<div class="temperature">
    <span>Washington, USA</span>
    <span id=temp>Temperature</span>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var uri = "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=washington&format=json&num_of_days=1&date=today&key=dfghjkiuytdfghjkj";
    var temp = 0
    $.get(uri, function(r,status) {
        current_temp_C = r.data.current_condition[0].temp_C;
        temp = r.data.current_condition[0].temp_C;
    }, "jsonp")
    $('#temp').text("hola " + temp)
</script>
```

I know this is probably not the best way I could do it, but any ideas?

Comment: The URL seems to return XML.

Comment: The url does not work because the key is of course not the real key
Please read this too https://www.facebook.com/notes/world-weather-online/introducing-faster-more-efficient-and-even-more-reliable-services/451128854963809

Comment: I didn't copy the actual key here. But that was not the issue because I return the data without problems. The question was the span update. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#temp').text("hola " + temp)` should be inside the get callback

```
var uri = "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=washington&format=json&num_of_days=1&date=today&key=dfghjkiuytdfghjkj"     
var temp = 0    ;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
$.get(uri, function(r,status) {                                                                                                                                                 
    current_temp_C = r.data.current_condition[0].temp_C;                                                                                              
    temp = r.data.current_condition[0].temp_C;                                                                                                        
    $('#temp').text("hola " + temp)       
}, "jsonp")
```

Comment: thanx. Actually I just realized that. I was about to delete the question. Tnks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Since it replies with an XML you may need to parse it first. Im not sure the exact tag you need but you could try this.

```
var uri = "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=washington&format=json&num_of_days=1&date=today&key=dfghjkiuytdfghjkj"

$.get(uri, function(data) {
var xml = $.parseXML(data);
var tempc= xml.find("temp_C").text();
$('#temp').text("hola " + tempc);
});
```

Check the url in your browser and see which tag gives the Information. Then simply on the line with xml.find("the tag").text(); should give you the result.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code i had not tested but may be this is use full for your problem...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=washington&format=json&num_of_days=1&date=today&key=dfghjkiuytdfghjkj"                   
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data) 
    {
        current_temp_C = r.data.current_condition[0].temp_C;                                                                                              
        temp = r.data.current_condition[0].temp_C;                        
        $('#temp').text("hola " + temp)
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) { console.log("An Error Occured " + error); }
});
```